# Mac mini WindowServer kernel panic multiple times a day with "a freed zone element has been modified"

Tags: macos, mac, crash, kernel-panic

I have been having trouble with my Mac mini. It randomly crashes several times a day. Sometimes it seems to be triggered by using any browser, but Chrome is the worst. YouTube seems to be the biggest culprit. I have completely wiped out the drive and re-installed the OS, but it didn't fix the problem. Here is my crash report. Can anyone help me figure this out?

```
Anonymous UUID:       CB3BF02C-464C-8459-F7F6-F1C55E8298B7

Sun Dec  7 12:00:53 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801f654ca4): "a freed zone element has been modified: expected 0xffffff803922d000 but found 0xffffff803822d000, bits changed 0x1000000, at offset 0 of 8192 in zone: kalloc.8192"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.115.4/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:461
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80b2ebbbd0 : 0xffffff801f622f79 
0xffffff80b2ebbc50 : 0xffffff801f654ca4 
0xffffff80b2ebbc90 : 0xffffff801f65273d 
0xffffff80b2ebbcf0 : 0xffffff801f651dc9 
0xffffff80b2ebbdf0 : 0xffffff801f62aa3f 
0xffffff80b2ebbe20 : 0xffffff801f613026 
0xffffff80b2ebbe50 : 0xffffff801f626b51 
0xffffff80b2ebbe80 : 0xffffff801f6139c5 
0xffffff80b2ebbef0 : 0xffffff801f61e013 
0xffffff80b2ebbf70 : 0xffffff801f6c9b9d 
0xffffff80b2ebbfb0 : 0xffffff801f6f4196 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
13F34

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.4.0: Sun Aug 17 19:50:11 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.115.4~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9477416E-7BCA-3679-AF97-E1EAAD3DD5A0
Kernel slide:     0x000000001f400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801f600000
System model name: Macmini4,1 (Mac-F2208EC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3922771313072
last loaded kext at 1054138173334: com.apple.filesystems.smbfs  2.0.3 (addr 0xffffff7fa1aa7000, size 335872)
last unloaded kext at 120126753416: com.apple.driver.AppleMCP89RootPortPM   1.11 (addr 0xffffff7fa1629000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 2.0.3
com.apple.filesystems.exfat 1.4
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch   80.14
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.0.9d7
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.34
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeLZVN 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.7
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    683.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.5.2
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.8.1b2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   660.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   656.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 217.92.1
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   217.92.1
com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothHIDKeyboard  170.15
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   170.15
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  245.13.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.6.22
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.6.3f4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.7fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.7f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.8
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.7f3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.6.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.6.3f4
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.7.1d6
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.12d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  660.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  656.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 660.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b4
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   640.36
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 686.4.1
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.11.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  23
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: Macmini4,1, BootROM MM41.0042.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.65f2
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1333 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353737334448302D4348392020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.7f3 14616, 3 services, 23 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en1
Serial ATA Device: TOSHIBA MK3255GSXF, 320.07 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-STDVDRW  GA32N
USB Device: Portable USB Drive
USB Device: V-Drive HDD
USB Device: Addonics USB Drive
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer...is responsible for switching the windows you see on your screen. Thus it could be a graphics problem.

Comment: If it is a graphics problem, do you have any suggestions on how pin point the issue? I appreciate any and all help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading and installing **memtest**. See if you have faulty memory. Or, just replace the chips you have with 2 x 4GB for a new total of 8GB. More RAM never hurt.